# How to make all google play services in same version

Tags: firebase, google-play-services, ionic4

'Cordova Play Services Version Adapter' has detected an error. The following dependencies of 'Google Play Services' are not compatible:
You have an incompatibility of versions with the following dependencies of 'Google Play Services':

```
- 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
- 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4'
- 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.0'
- 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+'
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+'
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+'
```

It doesn't exists a version of 'Google Play Services' that includes all these dependencies.
All dependencies of 'Google Play Services' must have the same version.
The application may not compile.

Comment: I don't know how Cordova works, but it looks like you're working with some really old versions of teh Firebase dependencies for Android.  The versions don't have to match any more, which means you are probably also using an old gradle plugin for Play services.